# Count the amount of occurrences of a another count result

Tags: mysql

We have a table called `entries` which stores user information against a date. Users are allowed to enter the database once per day. Some example data:

```
+----+------------------+----------+
| id |      email       |   date   |
+----+------------------+----------+
|  1 | marty@domain.com | 04.09.13 |
|  2 | john@domain.com  | 04.09.13 |
|  3 | marty@domain.com | 05.09.13 |
+----+------------------+----------+
```

I need to work out how many times there are `X` entries with the same email in the database. For example, the result should look like this for the above data, where we have 1 instance of one entry and 1 instance of 2 entries:

```
+---------------+-------+
| times_entered | total |
+---------------+-------+
|             1 |     1 |
|             2 |     1 |
+---------------+-------+
```

I've tried a few things but the furthest I have been able to get is getting a count of the amount of times each email address was found. It seems like all I need to do from here is collate those results and perform another COUNT on those groups to get the totals, but I'm unsure of how I can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will get the number of records per email:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS times_entered, email
FROM entries
GROUP BY email
```

Therefore, using this query as a derived table, we can group by the number of records to get the count (we do not need to select the `email` column in the subquery because we don't care about it):

```
SELECT times_entered, COUNT(1) AS total
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(1) AS times_entered
    FROM entries
    GROUP BY email
) x
GROUP BY times_entered
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a8d0/3)

[SQL Fiddle demo with a slightly larger data set](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1d15/2)

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. I really need to read into intermediate to advanced MySQL at some stage, I've never seen a nested SELECT like that before.

Answer (score 4):

Usually it can be something like

```
select times_entered, count(*) from 
( select count(*) times_entered from entries group by email )
group by times_entered
```

Not sure if it works for MySQL though...

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Not having it at hand, I ask myself can there be some limitation in MySQL SQL. At the time there was, but world changes... :-)

Comment: I believe sub queries were introduced in 4.1, almost ten years ago :)

Comment: I didn't know you can chose RDBMS. Excellent hint, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It could be something like this:

```
SELECT times_entered, COUNT( times_entered ) AS total
    FROM (
        SELECT COUNT( email ) AS times_entered
        FROM  `entries` 
        WHERE 1 
        GROUP BY email
    ) AS tmp
GROUP BY times_entered;
```