# What does this X in a query using a derived table in MySQL mean?

Tags: mysql

I'm getting my head around using what I think are called 'derived tables' in MySQL and noticed my queries only work when I have this `x` after the `FROM()` statement:

```
SELECT * FROM( <inner select> ) x ORDER BY id ASC
// -----------------------------^
```

I've looked around and read several articles about derived tables but none of them mention this (all the examples I see don't even utilise it, though my tests return 0 rows without it). I came across it in [an answer to one of my previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18651129/count-the-amount-of-occurrences-of-a-another-count-result).

If it makes any difference, I am running the queries via PDO.

Comment: Read this one - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/from-clause-subqueries.html

Comment: Like [DanFromGermany](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1948292/danfromgermany) said (originally in a comment, now in an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18692628/15168)), the X is an alias for the table generated by the inner select.  The SQL standard says the alias is mandatory.  It isn't really used here, but if you joined the inner select with another table, you'd use X to identify columns from the inner select.  You can usually (but not in Oracle) write 'AS X' which makes it clearer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ah, that makes perfect sense. It was a little confusing to me without the presence of an `AS`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `x` is an alias prefix for the subdataset. Just the same as picking from a table.

```
SELECT test_id from tableA x;
```

would make your results be accessable by `x.test_id`. This is good for shortening tables and summing subdatasets.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT test_id FROM tableA) x;
```

would offer `x.test_id`

Additional note by Jonathan Leffler: *The SQL standard says the alias is mandatory.*

Refere to this Blogpost about the advantages of alias: http://openquery.com/blog/good-practice-bad-practice-table-aliases

Answer (score 4):

`x` is the name given to the resulting table which comes from the **inner select**. The name could be any valid table name not just `x`.

> Subqueries are legal in a SELECT statement's FROM clause. The actual
>   syntax is:
>
> ```
> SELECT ... FROM (subquery) [AS] name ...
> ```
>
> The [AS] name clause is mandatory, because every table in a FROM
>   clause must have a name.

**Reference**: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/from-clause-subqueries.html